# SQL syntax with simple WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I'm having a problem with updating a table where the id matches the post-id. My code looks like this at the moment.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$vote =$_POST['vote'];           
$sql = "UPDATE images SET votes=votes+1, value=value+$vote, WHERE 'id'='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
echo "hej då";
```

Comment: Maybe you should label your question with PHP and MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$sql = "UPDATE images SET votes=votes+1, value=value+'$vote' WHERE id='$id'";
```

Comment: you have to use single quotes inside query for php variables mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your query appears a bit off.  Try removing the single quotes around `$id` in the `WHERE` clause, and also get rid of that trailing comma after the `SET` list.

```
$sql = "UPDATE images SET votes=votes+1, value=value+$vote WHERE id=$id";
```

Comment: Thanks for qiuck respons, badly that doesnt seems to help.

Comment: this is the message I´m getting: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE 'id'=' at line 1

Comment: Sorry...you had apostrophes around the field.  Use backticks instead, e.g. `\`id\``

Comment: try without backticks and apostrophes

Comment: Give the people want they want.  Backticks removed.

Comment: is it php with MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "UPDATE images SET votes=votes+1, value=value+$vote, WHERE 'id'='".$id."'";
```